# Play console suddenly started review internal testing

Tags: google-play-console

I am using Play console internal testing with fastlane upload.

Suddenly, Google started review my internal testing.

I know the internal testing is fast distribution process without review for small internal tester group.

Is there any change in policy? I can't understand this issue
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get a response from google play console help support team.

In my case, my last release was rejected because of invalid test id/password.

So second case includes my case.

```
Hi there,
I'm sorry we got disconnected during our chat today - please let us know how we can help resolve your issue. If you'd prefer to contact us again via chat support, we're available Monday through Friday, 12 am to 12 am GMT.

We also offer email support 24/7. Just respond to this email and I (or one of my teammates) can pick up where we left off.

In most cases, if you upload an app bundle to an internal test track, changes will be immediately available. App updates on internal test tracks are not subject to reviews but may be subject to retroactive reviews after going live on the Play store.

There are two caveats to note regarding reviews and internal test tracks:

If your app's first release roll-out is on an internal test track, the submission must be reviewed before it can be published. Reviews can take a few hours or up to 7 days (or longer in exceptional cases), as it depends on the review time that your app is subject to.
If your previous submission has been rejected, the next submission must be reviewed before it can be published. In this case, if you upload an app bundle to an internal test track, changes will not become available until the review is complete and approved.
Regards,
Belle
Google Play Developer Support
```